# Scanf in while loop not able to input anything

Tags: c, linux

I'm using a Linux 2.0.26 VM and never have this problem.

The while loop works because I added a printf inside it in order to test it.

```
#include <stdio.h>

#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

void main()
{
    int i;

    mknod("pipe.txt", S_IFIFO | 0666, 0);
    for (i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
        if (fork() == 0) {
            if (i == 0)
                to_pipe();
            //else
            //    pipe_a_archivo();
        }
    }
    wait(NULL);
    unlink("pipe.txt");
}

void to_pipe()
{
    int num, fdini;

    fdini = open("pipe.txt", O_WRONLY);
    do {
        //printf("Test");
        scanf("%d", &num);
        write(fdini, &num, sizeof(int));
    } while (num != 0);

    close(fdini);
    unlink("pipe.txt");
    exit();
}
```

This program should get numbers from keyboard and write them in a file. My problem is that whenever I execute the program from the command line, nothing happens, `scanf()` doesn't work because it doesn't let me input any number. I know for sure that the loop works because if uncomment `printf()` it prints on the screen.  Any help on solving this problem?

Comment: Does the file EXIST,when you run the program?

Comment: Check the return value from every library function you use.

Comment: it does @wildplasser

Comment: how can I do that @WeatherVane

Comment: Works perfectly here, with a correct wrapper. What makes you think that "`scanf` doesn't work because it doesn't let me input any number"?

Comment: The thing is that it works on other people's VM and not on mine, I know it doesn't work because you know when you do an scanf, the program "stops" to ask you for a number, but in this case it doesn't, it doesn't stop and I cannot input any number. @WeatherVane

Comment: You look at each library function man page, read what it returns, amd why, and then check that the function operated as it was supposed to. In the case of `open()` it returns the value of -1 to indicate an error,

Comment: I see you have added a pipe and a fork to the question. Be sure as to what you are asking, and, the only function result you have checked is from `fork`.

Comment: @WeatherVane I 've just added more code,  I can comment the pipe and everything related to it and still wont work

Comment: Your code does not compile. For example missing `;` in `int num,fdini`

Comment: Since the focus is on `scanf` can you get it to work without using any other functions except `printf`?

Comment: You could put a `printf("num=%d\n", num);` ***after*** the scanf to see if the scanf worked. It's not clear whether it will work. After forking twice, you have three processes all fighting over the same terminal input. I'm not sure how that gets resolved.

Comment: @WeatherVane if I code an scanf just after mknod it works

Comment: @user3386109 starts printing "num 1073792080" infinitely and doesn't let me write any number

Comment: That usually means that scanf saw a character that's not a digit. You should check the return value from scanf. `if (scanf("%d", &num) != 1) { printf("Bad\n"); exit(1); }`

Comment: @user3386109 it doesn't print anything at all

Comment: I think you need to find someone who can sit next to you, and watch what you're doing. I wrote a quick test program that forks twice, and calls `scanf` from both children. The input alternates between the two children, but otherwise works normally.

Comment: @user3386109 it feels like the problem is related to the VM because another partner of mine has the same problem but other don't, it's weird

Comment: 1) `void main()` is an invalid signature for `main`. It should be `int main(void)`. 2) `void to_pipe()` should be `void to_pipe(void)`. 3) Indent your code and format it the nicest you can, if you want others to read it. 4) As Nellie said, this code does not even compile. Missing `;` (solved ;)). Compile every code you post here before hand. Preferently with a high level of warnings flags such as `gcc -std=c17 -pedantic -Wall -Wextra -Werror`, so that you see the obvious errors by yourself. And disable them only when you know what you're doing.

Comment: 5) `sizeof`: It's usually a better idea to do `sizeof(num)` than `sizeof(int)` so that if you change the type of `num` some day, your code doesn't break.  6) `exit();` is wrong. Check `man exit`; it needs an argument.

Comment: You create a FIFO the hard way, using `mknod()` instead of `mkfifo()`. Once you've created it, you launch two process that attempt to open it for writing. Neither of those will complete the open until there's a process that opens the same FIFO for reading — but there is no evidence in the code shown that there is a process reading unless the commented out `pipe_a_archivo()` function call would do that. If that's present on other people's machines and not on yours, that may be sufficient reason for the program not to work for you. You don't error check function calls; you've no idea what fails!

Answer (score 0):

I think that most of your problem is due to you not implementing the `pipe_a_archivo()` function to read from the FIFO and write the data to a file.  Certainly, the code in the question is not a good MCVE ([Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)).  Amongst other problems, there is no action for the second iteration of the loop.

This code error checks function calls, and includes a plausible implementation of `pipe_a_archivo()`, and then works sensibly:

```
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <unistd.h>

static void to_pipe(void);
static void pipe_a_archivo(void);

#define FIFO_NAME "pipe.txt"
#define FILE_NAME "archive.txt"

int main(void)
{
    if (mkfifo(FIFO_NAME, 0666) != 0)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "failed to create FIFO '%s'\n", FIFO_NAME);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    if (fork() == 0)
        to_pipe();
    if (fork() == 0)
        pipe_a_archivo();
    int corpse;
    int status;
    while ((corpse = wait(&status)) > 0)
        printf("PID %d exited with status 0x%.4X\n", corpse, status);
    unlink("pipe.txt");
}

static void to_pipe(void)
{
    int num, fdini;

    fdini = open(FIFO_NAME, O_WRONLY);
    do
    {
        printf("Enter a number: ");
        fflush(stdout);
        scanf("%d", &num);
        write(fdini, &num, sizeof(int));
    } while (num != 0);

    close(fdini);
    exit(0);
}

static void pipe_a_archivo(void)
{
    int fd_in = open(FIFO_NAME, O_RDONLY);
    if (fd_in < 0)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed to open FIFO '%s' for reading\n", FIFO_NAME);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    FILE *fp_out = fopen(FILE_NAME, "w");
    if (fp_out == NULL)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed to open file '%s' for writing\n", FILE_NAME);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    int num;
    while (read(fd_in, &num, sizeof(num)) == sizeof(num))
    {
        fprintf(fp_out, "%d\n", num);
    }

    close(fd_in);
    fclose(fp_out);
    exit(0);
}
```

I removed the loop in `main()` because a loop that tests which iteration it is on and then calls an appropriate function is really not a good design.  This code also only deletes the FIFO in the main program, and only after both child processes have exited.

Sample run:

```
$ ./fifo29
Enter a number: 23
Enter a number: 34
Enter a number: 12931344
Enter a number: 0
PID 10939 exited with status 0x0000
PID 10940 exited with status 0x0000
$ cat archive.txt
23
34
12931344
0
$
```